CountUp Timer Inside ListView.builder
The goal is to set an independent count up timer in each list item. This is a follow up on this Question. I couldn't figure out how to make the code work. I have added the parameters xParameterA, xParameter B to each of the functions and they don't show any errors but the count up functionality isn't working.
These are the 2 functions I have trouble with.
Function Timer Increment
  // Increments the time
  // I have added the parameter "xParameterA" here to call inside the list
  void xCountUpActionAddTime(Duration xParameterA) {

    final xAddSeconds = 1;

    setState(() {
      final seconds = xParameterA.inSeconds + xAddSeconds;

      xParameterA = Duration(seconds: seconds);
    });
  }

Function Starting The Timer
// Starts the timer
  // I have added the parameter "xParameterB" here to call inside the list
  void xCountUpActionStart(Duration xParameterB) {
    xCountUpActionEnd();

    xCountUpTime = Timer.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => xCountUpActionAddTime(xParameterB));
  }

Count Up Full Code
Duration xCountUpDuration = Duration();

  Timer? xCountUpTime;

  // Increments the time
  // I have added the parameter "xParameterA" here to call inside the list
  void xCountUpActionAddTime(Duration xParameterA) {

    final xAddSeconds = 1;

    setState(() {
      final seconds = xParameterA.inSeconds + xAddSeconds;

      xParameterA = Duration(seconds: seconds);
    });
  }

  // Stops the timer
  void xCountUpActionEnd() {
    setState(() => xCountUpTime?.cancel());
  }

  // Starts the timer
  // I have added the parameter "xParameterB" here to call inside the list
  void xCountUpActionStart(Duration xParameterB) {
    xCountUpActionEnd();

    xCountUpTime = Timer.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => xCountUpActionAddTime(xParameterB));
  }


  // Sets the initial duration of the timer
  Widget xCountUpTimerWidget(Duration xParameterC) {

    String xDigitConverter(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    final xHours = xDigitConverter(xParameterC.inHours);

    final xMinutes = xDigitConverter(xParameterC.inMinutes.remainder(60));

    final xSeconds = xDigitConverter(xParameterC.inSeconds.remainder(60));

    return Text(
      '$xHours:$xMinutes:$xSeconds',
      style: xDisplayTaskTime,
    );
  }

Code Inside ListView.Builder
return ListView.builder(
   itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {

   Duration xInnerCountUpDuration = Duration(hours: 00, minutes: 10, seconds: 00);


   return Container(
     child: GestureDetector(
       onTap: () {
         setState(() {
            if (xStateActiveItem != index) {

               xStateActiveItem = index;

               xCountUpActionAddTime(xInnerCountUpDuration);

               xCountUpActionStart(xInnerCountUpDuration);

           } else {

               xStateActiveItem = null;

               xCountUpActionEnd();
          }
      });
  },),);

Code To Display The Count Up Timer Inside The List
Align(

   alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

   child: xCountUpTimerWidget(xInnerCountUpDuration),

)


"The goal is to set an independent count up timer in each list item" - what is that timer supposed to do actually? lats say you set it to one minute (with one second repetition), what next?

@pskink There is a count up timer on each list item. When a list item is clicked the count up timer only for that list item should start counting up, that's the goal. If I implement the code without parameters, the count up timer on all list items start counting.

so  if you want to update only one particular list item then wrap it with ListenableBuilder / ValueListenableBuilder for example

@pskink I can't replace listview builder, I don't know if listenablebuilder can be used inside a listview builder. Anyway seems complex, if you can show via code how to do it that would be great. Is it overly complex what I am trying to do?

ListView.builder(itemCount: ..., itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ValueListenableBuilder(...

@pskink When I place the Code 1 from link inside the itembuilder, it doesn't work, if I place it right inside the class extends code it works, can you please explain why it doesn't work inside itembuilder.

i have no idea what you mean by class extends

@pskink I meant view state code class _ViewState extends State { }

and where is ValueListenableBuilder in your code?

@pskink Yes it doesn't have the ValueListenableBuilder but I just want to understand why that code works when it's inside view state but when the code is placed inside itembuilder it doesn't work.
